# Issue while Building/Compiling flutter application

Tags: java, android, gradle, kotlin, flutter

Getting this error every time I try to build my flutter application

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not download kotlin-gradle-plugin.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.3.50/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.3.50.jar'.
         > Connection reset
   > Could not download kotlin-annotation-processing-gradle.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-annotation-processing-gradle:1.3.50)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-annotation-processing-gradle/1.3.50/kotlin-annotation-processing-gradle-1.3.50.jar'.
         > Connection reset
   > Could not download kotlin-android-extensions.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:1.3.50)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-android-extensions/1.3.50/kotlin-android-extensions-1.3.50.jar'.
         > Connection reset
   > Could not download kotlin-compiler-embeddable.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable:1.3.50)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-compiler-embeddable/1.3.50/kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.3.50.jar'.
         > Connection reset

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 37m 42s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I'm running Windows 10.
Ran Flutter Doctor, everything seems fine from there.

Please help me debug this, seems like I could never start android development. Wasted all of yesterday to debug everything and now this..

Comment: are you using a VPN or do you have DNS servers configured?

Comment: No, I'm not using any VPN and I guess I have my SND configured too cause I'm on WIFI